# 530 Login incorrect, when using lftp

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, synchronization, lftp

I am trying to sync a local folder with a ftp folder using `lftp` in a Linux Mint OS. I adapted a script which worked at first. But don't know why, it stopped working. This is the script

```
  #!/bin/bash

  #get username and password
  USER="user"                               #Your username
  PASS="password"                           #Your password
  HOST="ftp://ftp.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com/" #Keep just the address
  LCD="/home/mario/MEGA/analizaR/public"    #Your local directory
  RCD="/www/analizar"                       #FTP server directory

  lftp -f "
  set ssl:verify-certificate false  
  set sftp:auto-confirm no
  set ftp:use-feat false
  open $HOST
  user $USER $PASS
  lcd $LCD
  mirror --continue --reverse --delete --verbose $LCD $RCD
  bye
  "
```

I get an error saying `530 Login incorrect`. I checked several times that my user and password are perfect, but still getting this error.

Any idea?

---

### EDIT

Logging using Filezilla

#### Using FTP- File Transfer Protocol (unconnected)

```
2019-08-01 09:31:52 6823 1 Status: Resolving address of ftp.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com
2019-08-01 09:31:52 6823 1 Status: Connecting to 46.231.127.37:21...
2019-08-01 09:31:52 6823 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2019-08-01 09:31:52 6823 1 Response: 220 Servidor FTP preparado.
2019-08-01 09:31:52 6823 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2019-08-01 09:32:12 6823 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2019-08-01 09:32:12 6823 1 Error: Could not connect to server
2019-08-01 09:32:12 6823 1 Status: Waiting to retry...
2019-08-01 09:32:17 6823 1 Status: Resolving address of ftp.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com
2019-08-01 09:32:17 6823 1 Status: Connecting to 46.231.127.37:21...
2019-08-01 09:32:17 6823 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2019-08-01 09:32:17 6823 1 Response: 220 Servidor FTP preparado.
2019-08-01 09:32:17 6823 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2019-08-01 09:32:37 6823 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2019-08-01 09:32:37 6823 1 Error: Could not connect to server
```

#### Using SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol (connected)

```
2019-08-01 09:35:53 6893 1 Status: Connecting to ftp.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com...
2019-08-01 09:35:53 6893 1 Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
2019-08-01 09:35:53 6893 1 Command: open "vivaelsoftwarelibre@ftp.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com" 22
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Command: Trust new Hostkey: Once
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Command: Pass: ****************
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Status: Connected to ftp.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/www/analizar"...
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Command: cd "/www/analizar"
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Error: Directory /www/analizar: no such file or directory
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Command: pwd
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Response: Current directory is: "/usr/home/vivaelsoftwarelibre"
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Command: ls
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Status: Listing directory /usr/home/vivaelsoftwarelibre
2019-08-01 09:36:32 6893 1 Status: Directory listing of "/usr/home/vivaelsoftwarelibre" successful
```

#### Using FTP Protocol (Only use plain FTP (insecure)) (connected)

```
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Resolving address of ftp.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Connecting to 46.231.127.37:21...
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 220 Servidor FTP preparado.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: USER vivaelsoftwarelibre
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 331 Please specify the password.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: PASS ****************
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 230 Login successful.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: SYST
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: FEAT
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 211-Features:
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  AUTH TLS
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  EPRT
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  EPSV
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  MDTM
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  PASV
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  PBSZ
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  PROT
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  SIZE
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response:  TVFS
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 211 End
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Logged in
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/www/analizar"...
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: CWD /www/analizar
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: PWD
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 257 "/www/analizar"
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: TYPE I
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: PORT 192,168,1,129,226,121
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: LIST
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 226 Directory send OK.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Command: MDTM 404.html
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Response: 213 20190320224424
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Timezone offset of server is 0 seconds.
2019-08-01 09:46:47 7154 1 Status: Directory listing of "/www/analizar" successful
```

Comment: Can you login to that server anyhow, using any other client, running on the same machine as your lftp script?

Comment: I can get access using those credentials in any web browser.

Comment: On the same machine as the lftp script? + What URL do you use? + Anyway, we would need  a log file and I'm not sure if you can get it from a webbrowser. So can you try a real FTP client, which can do logging?

Comment: I tried using Filezilla, and only got access when using protocol SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol. Can this be the problem instead of using FTP - File transfer protocol?

Comment: I edited the question by adding the logs using FTP and SFTP

Comment: FileZilla is trying encrypted connection. Try using plain unecrypted connection.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Come on! There's a box for that on FileZilla Site Manager dialog.

Comment: Ok, I was in SFTP, that's why I did not see the dialog. Using `Only use plain FTP (insecure)` option, it connected. You can see the log in the question.

Comment: How can the script be edited to connect succesfully?

Comment: Do you run FileZilla on the same machine as lftp? + Post a log file from lftp too.

Comment: Yes for the first question. I am getting an error when logging the `lftp`. Adding this to the last line of the script `">>$LOG` I get this error `bash: $LOG: ambiguous redirect`. The same using `">>"$LOG"`

Answer (score 4):

`lftp` accepts passwords with symbols if you enclose them with quotes:

```
lftp -u user,'pas$w#' host:port -e 'ls; exit;'
```

or:

```
lftp user:'pas$w#'@host:port -e 'ls; exit;'
```

Answer (score 1):

lftp 4.8.1 [man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) says `-f` option requires a file name, a string with line breaks & command lines won't serve your needs.

Either store your lftp command lines inside a file and use the filename after `-f` option:

```
lftp -f lftp_commands.txt
```

Or use `-c` option:

> Commands can be separated with a semicolon, `&&` or `||`. Remember to quote the commands argument properly in the shell.

Comment: I'm trying to use the -f option: lftp -f filename.txt.  My filename has these contents but I get pw error message. Any ideas? filename.txt:open -u useruser,'pwpw' ftp://MMMMSITE <<EOF
LOG TRANSACTIONS /appl/tmp/m_Ftp_trans.tmp
  lcd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
  pwd
  cd transfer/
  ls
  put test4.txt
  bye
EOF

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing my password to only characters and numbers (and no symbols).

I had the same issue. All commands seemed correct. Could connect with all ftp programs, but not with lftp. Then I changed my ftp password to only numbers and characters and it suddenly worked! Guess lftp command breaks when the password contains a (specific) symbol.